# Stylesheet not applying correctly to elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, sorry for not providing the ALL the needed code. Let me explain the reason and it's not simply because of private info and codes... the project is really extensive and all coded by hand without any framework, so the only way to perfectly reproduce the exactly same situation would be having the whole project, so my words are the only reference.

Ok... let's get going...

I have a Stylesheet that changes all buttons:

```
button{
    font-family: 'autobus';
    font-size: 15px;
    background: rgb(8,77,110);
    border: 1px solid rgb(231,235,245);
    color: rgb(231,235,245);
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And a few others that changes really specific buttons:

```
.innerForm > button {
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-right: -25px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

After developing a part of my system where I can add some elements containing input and buttons through some input and buttons I realized that something really was with an unexpected behavior...

[image: Interface unexpected behavior occurence]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fssa12-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/75279149_3354929641214531_2545868472026398720_n.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_eui2=AeF1aYHE-o2SWZw4TEHlBT2CV8Gl1JHAyOnefKvcJlmyznAuYyxJA2iL_h2L0O5eBRbuxtKmw0-l-3GJdHgACCF5uMtgI077YPOr5ULciXxQBA&_nc_oc=AQlU8bolM2v5Trj8sz8wUPdZvdJSnbm8DdJtmA5F20EI7SaMupEc0CIzNJPL8XaJRKE&_nc_ht=scontent.fssa12-1.fna&oh=d8d18c84bd48a717b56001ebf8c78d12&oe=5E1E650B))</sub>

As you can see, only on the newly javascript added "input+button" the button respects the CSS... I realized only after adding the elements that the ones coming already build from the server were with different styling because I'd liked them without the background... anyway both are exactly the same in the browser html as you can see:

[image: HTML/Code of the First Image]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fssa12-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/73403885_3354942407879921_8213671551082430464_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&_nc_eui2=AeGZwk_EB8WjZZ3QWTC5krkQrOdzEcsz4JFCOpsHEV8Tj_-roEPyBGkXv2ahjMzYZuRLQT6BHyM1NXpmsoLXPNOY2d9E-Gcd5kcFRGjUwvCnKg&_nc_oc=AQmaTvbTjZ-vGO-zNJQ0S8eyT70BoO2Wn7pB-JadHpvH6g6iynovGX84-ufJFVqrgFg&_nc_ht=scontent.fssa12-1.fna&oh=1904e01718596f09da4991d95d2a6dcf&oe=5E59979F))</sub>

No classes... only one onclick attribute to call the javascript function to remove the item. All the others "specific buttons stylizing" have the

```
cursor: pointer;
```

While these backgroundless buttons doesn't even changes the cursor appearance...

If it wasn't a really messy one I wouldn't even bother myself on coming to ask here.

Any other needed info, just comment and I can edit adding it.

So... anyone has ever seen something like that?

PS: If someone answer why the javascript added item doesn't show on HTML it's "value='21/12/2019'" and still shows it on the visual interface, I'll upvote too for the explaination. And in case the main question doesn't acquire a proper answer, I'll vote this "value issue" explanation as the answer if someone answer correctly.

Comment: The first one's tag is spelled buttom (emphasis on last letter), not button. Looks like you have a typo. Also, when you say JS added item doesn't how on HTML, do you mean if you view page source? It should show in the console if the inspect the element.

Comment: Realized that after bringing the string echoed from the server to HTML structure... VSCode acused that. Keen eye @ThomasFitzgerald. If you answer that I will choose it as the answer.

Comment: Anything about the PostScript? Why does the value is "occulted"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see at the HTML image, "buttoM" was misspelled. The correct would be "button". This changing fixed the issue.

[image: Image with the intended behavior]
<sub>(source: [fbcdn.net](https://scontent.fssa12-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/73472647_3355010784539750_5661607399752990720_n.jpg?_nc_cat=108&_nc_eui2=AeHz4XursgjrY8A2G8vjn6M_qHW8Mx51bQ_KtIXCotPe4sJ7nQGnqP1buY_2vh4Jew8K90thS5tzRS9S8NqG5FJg6R5AsnDyTojiEsw15AznHg&_nc_oc=AQlWs3iD2b7ZlZAMcsWjzJ96H_eVWsCYu8I88S7ywkRZLFEeVyCIiLnsmWwVDBHPtVA&_nc_ht=scontent.fssa12-1.fna&oh=6cb7e4f37a978eda88d8a0d53a84c321&oe=5E2F8232))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the tag name was misspelled. The button selector is selecting all tags spelled button. Should you have had an additional selector for buttom, it should have picked up the styling, although that is certainly not what you were looking for.

Always a good idea to run your html through a validation tool. Just google HTML Validtor. Any of them should work out. Also, it is a good idea to use a linter for your JS to help find any potential mistakes.

The html code generated by JS should be available in the dev console as well. Better to use the dev console than viewing the page source in many cases like this.

An additional note for CSS is to use a tool such as AutoPrefixer to apply vendor prefixes if you have a requirement to support older browsers.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Actually VSCode validates the HTML... but before I realize this misspeling this was a string in server side language (PHP), and while string the Intelisense wouldn't point that out... exactly when I did pass it to HTML block the editor pointed things out.